# Why must the template parameter pack be last?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, variadic-templates

I am facing the following inconsistency between `gcc10.2` and `clang11`:

```
template<typename ... Args, typename T>
static constexpr int fuu = sizeof(T);
```

`clang` complains that a template pack must be the last thing in the template declaration:

```
error: template parameter pack must be the last template parameter
template<typename ... Args, typename T>
```

but `gcc` is cool with it.
See https://godbolt.org/z/v9KeW6

Is this "last thing" actually a rule? In a function this works with both compilers.

```
template<typename... Args, typename T>
int foo(T) {
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

I don't see a reason why the first snippet shouldn't work, the template arguments are unambiguously deducible.

Comment: if you add `int main () { fuu<int>; }` you get an error also from gcc

Comment: yes, and thats also a weird one, isnt it? `wrong number of template parameters. is one, should be at least one`

Comment: Yes: weird and funny. But the substance is that, for a list of template parameters where nothing can be deduced and all has to be explicated, the variadic list has to be at the end. Different for a `foo()` function where `T` can be deduced.

Comment: `template<typename ... Ts> static constexpr std::size_t fuu = (sizeof(Ts, ...);` with C++17 fold expression :-)

Comment: do you know where this comes from? What belongs to `Args` and what to `T` is clear from the explicit list one gives..

Comment: @Jarod42 - Never underestimate the power of the comma operator :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable template declaration is ill-formed, and it's a gcc bug for not diagnosing it.

From [temp.param#14](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#14):

> ... If a template-parameter of a primary class template, **primary variable template**, or alias template is a template parameter pack, it **shall be** the last template-parameter. ...

The function template is fine, since the rules for function templates are different. If the template parameters after the parameter pack can be deduced by the arguments provided at the call site, then the template is ok.